# Why Servlet is not outputting this html?

Tags: java, servlets

I am learning to connect my servlet to database. I have two columns in my db (Username,Password). I want to create a program that access the database compares the User/Pass (send via the user form html ) with the values in db columns. When i try to login , nothing shows up on screen .

Files:

LoginServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void init(){}

Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
    try{

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<p>Servlet is loading</p>");



    String TheUser=req.getParameter("username");
    String ThePass=req.getParameter("password");

    try{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","pass");

        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select Username,Password from AllUsers");
        String compareUser=rs.getString(1);
        String comparePass=rs.getString(2);



            if(TheUser.equals(compareUser)||ThePass.equals(comparePass)){

                out.println("<p>You are logged in as " + compareUser+" </p>");

            }
            else
                out.println("Wrong Combination");

            }

        }catch(Exception e){}

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException|IOException|ServletException f){
      f.printStackTrace();          
 }

out.println("</html></body>");
out.close();

}

public void destroy(){}
}
```

This File Compiles and deployed.

web.xml:

```
<web-app>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SignUpServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SignUp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

log.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name='loginForm' method='post' action='login'>

        Enter Username:
        <input type='text' name='username'>
        </br>

        Enter Password:
        <input type='password' name='password'>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S: Servlet is loading. The `<p>Servlet is loading </p>` tag shows up on browser.

Comment: Instead of discarding all exceptions (`}catch(ClassNotFoundException|IOException|ServletException f){}`), make sure they show up in your log files, e.g. with `f.printStackTrace()`. Then have a look at your server looks on whether an exception occurred.

Comment: unrelated to your question, please consider to 1./ make sure all opened jdbc connections are closed (connection leak); 2./ use try-with-resources; 3./ use a connection pool through named resources (requires some setup on your server); 4./ naming conventions for local variables; 5./ avoid catch-all-and-ignore

Comment: @TimoSta caught it. No help, still nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i did it. After many hours of hit n try. I figured out that the db cursor was never on the first records of the table , that's why it didnt show up.
I wrapped the code in a while statement:

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select Username,Password from AllUsers");

        while(rs.next()){
            String compareUser=rs.getString(1);
            String comparePass=rs.getString(2);

            if(TheUser.equals(compareUser)||ThePass.equals(comparePass)){

                out.println("<p>You are logged in as " +compareUser+"</p>");
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();


            }
            else{

                out.println("<p>Wrong Combination</p>");
                out.println("</br><a href='log.html'>Login</a></p>");

                rs.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();
            }
        }    

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I hope if anyone else runs into this problem, this could help.